# nim: Use a static library

Tags: static-libraries, static-linking, nim-lang

I've tried to get an audio library statically linked to my program. I use [this](https://github.com/zacharycarter/soloud-nim) nimble package. To get it run, i had to build the soloud library as described [here](http://sol.gfxile.net/soloud/premake.html). For short after download i ran "genie --with-miniaudio-only --platform=x64 vs2017" in the "build" folder and got the source code to generate the dynamic and the static library. For now i can run the following demo program from the nimble package with the generated dll alongside:

```
import solouddotnim, times, os

var i, spin = 0

var sl : ptr Soloud

sl = Soloud_create()

discard Soloud_init(sl)

Soloud_setGlobalVolume(sl, 1)


var stream = WavStream_create()
discard WavStream_load(cast[ptr Wav](stream), "test.ogg")

let currentTime = epochTime()
let length = WavStream_getLength(stream)
discard Soloud_play(cast[ptr Soloud](sl), cast[ptr Wav](stream))

while epochTime() - currentTime <= length:
  sleep(100)

Soloud_deinit(sl)

Soloud_destroy(sl)
```

Now to the static-link part. In the solouddotnim.nim file of the nimble package i use, i see this part:

```
when defined(windows):
  const
    libname* = "libsoloud.dll"
elif ...
```

So i simple changed the windows part to the following, re-installed the nimble-package and placed the "soloud_static_x64.lib" alongside to the "main.nim" of the testproject:

```
when defined(windows):
  const
    libname* = "soloud_static_x64.lib"
elif ...
```

But this doesent make it. (cant open "soloud_static_x64.lib" error when build)
Evereywhere where the constant "libname" is used there are the pragmas "cdecl", "importc" and "dynlib". For example:

```
proc Soloud_create*(): ptr Soloud {.cdecl, importc: "Soloud_create", dynlib: libname.}
```

So "dynlib" is telling nim to use a dll on windows. But was is the pragma for static libraries?
In the nim documentations i only found [DynlibOverride](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#dynliboverride) to link to static libraries, but i dont understand the example and here is where i stuck. I've tried the followings:

```
nim c --dynlibOverride:libname --passL:soloud_static_x64.lib "examples\00-ogg\Example00_ogg.nim"

nim c --dynlibOverride:soloudtotnim --passL:soloud_static_x64.lib "examples\00-ogg\Example00_ogg.nim"
```

Firstly i dont know what parameter dynlibOverride expects and secondly both compiles, but dont work. It expects a dynamic library alongside the exe.
My last try was to remove all dynlib pragmas from the nimble package. But now i cant compile it.

```
undefined reference to `Soloud_create'
...
Error: execution of an external program failed: 'gcc.exe...
```

My knowlege ends here. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I could not get any of your solutions work. I break down the problem as small as possible so everybody can reproduce this:
"foo.nim" contains this:

```
proc add*(a, b: int): int {.cdecl, exportc.} = 
    a + b
proc sub*(a, b: int): int {.cdecl, exportc.} = 
    a - b
```

The .lib is simply generated with this command: "nim c --app:staticlib foo.nim"

Now to use it i created a file "main.nim" with this content:

```
{.passL:"foo.lib".}
proc add*(a, b: int):int {.cdecl, importc.}
proc sub*(a, b: int):int {.cdecl, importc.}

echo add(10, 5)
echo sub(10, 5)
```

if i simply build it with "nim c -r main.nim", i get the following output and  error:

```
P:\Nim\LearnCBinding>nim c -r main.nim
Hint: used config file 'C:\nim-1.5.1\config\nim.cfg' [Conf]    
Hint: used config file 'C:\nim-1.5.1\config\config.nims' [Conf]
....CC: stdlib_io.nim
CC: stdlib_system.nim
CC: main.nim

Hint:  [Link]
foo.lib(@mfoo.nim.c.o):@mfoo.nim.c:(.text+0x1f6): multiple definition of `PreMainInner'     
C:\Users\Peter\nimcache\main_d\@mmain.nim.c.o:@mmain.nim.c:(.text+0x120): first defined here
foo.lib(@mfoo.nim.c.o):@mfoo.nim.c:(.text+0x20a): multiple definition of `PreMain'
C:\Users\Peter\nimcache\main_d\@mmain.nim.c.o:@mmain.nim.c:(.text+0x134): first defined here
foo.lib(@mfoo.nim.c.o):@mfoo.nim.c:(.text+0x240): multiple definition of `NimMainInner'     
C:\Users\Peter\nimcache\main_d\@mmain.nim.c.o:@mmain.nim.c:(.text+0x16f): first defined here
foo.lib(@mfoo.nim.c.o):@mfoo.nim.c:(.text+0x254): multiple definition of `NimMain'
C:\Users\Peter\nimcache\main_d\@mmain.nim.c.o:@mmain.nim.c:(.text+0x183): first defined here
foo.lib(@mfoo.nim.c.o):@mfoo.nim.c:(.text+0x285): multiple definition of `main'
C:\Users\Peter\nimcache\main_d\@mmain.nim.c.o:@mmain.nim.c:(.text+0x1b4): first defined here
foo.lib(@mfoo.nim.c.o):@mfoo.nim.c:(.text+0x2da): multiple definition of `NimMainModule'
C:\Users\Peter\nimcache\main_d\@mmain.nim.c.o:@mmain.nim.c:(.text+0x209): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: execution of an external program failed: 'C:\nim-1.5.1\dist\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe   -o P:\Nim\LearnCBinding\main.exe  C:\Users\Peter\nimcache\main_d\stdlib_io.nim.c.o C:\Users\Peter\nimcache\main_d\stdlib_system.nim.c.o C:\Users\Peter\nimcache\main_d\@mmain.nim.c.o  foo.lib   '
```

Because of the multiple definition error i also tried to build foo.lib with parameter "--noMain:on", but it doesnt make any difference.

Do you have the same problem? By the way i use the current version of Nim "nim-1.5.1" and reinstalled MingW with the finish.exe from nim.

Comment: Use passC to pass option to the C compiler and passL to pass option to the linker. 
There is clib to link a C library. Yopu can pretty much link the library exactly ho you would do it in C with this.

Comment: It's documented in the Manual if you haven't found it yet ;) https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#implementation-specific-pragmas-passc-pragma.

Comment: Thanks. But i dont have that much experience. What does this mean to the binding? Do i have to replace all "dynlib" pragmas with the "passc" and "link" pragma like `{.link: "soloud_static_x64.lib", passc:"-L soloud_static_x64".}`?

Comment: Remove all {.dynlib.}, retain the {.importc.} and add one single {.passL.} that links the library.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but i am not able to get this work. See my edit for a simple example.

Comment: Note that compiling the nim program includes the nim runtime. That's why you get the multiple definitions error. Try practicing writing and linking the foo example in c to nim. I believe that will help by solving a similar topic at a smaller scope.

Comment: For now it looks like a bug. I reported it here https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/7080. After these answers i opened a bug report here https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/15955

Answer (score 1):

I will try to help you with the following error you have:

```
undefined reference to `Soloud_create'
```

but i will assume that you have configured your environment so you can compile your nim programs with visual studio compiler (by adding --cc:vcc to your compile command)
this is because you already seem  to have visual studio 2017 and you are compiling soloud static library with it. I think this is the best option when you are compiling with one compiler both: static library and executable that will use it.

open your static library (soloud_static_x64.lib) with some text/hex editor and search for "Soloud_create". i guess you will not find anything. so why is that? because for some reason author decided to not include "C interfacing" in a static library project. so it contains only C++ symbols and not pure C symbols that are needed for our solouddotnim.nim module.

let's try to find out what .cpp file we need for that. i noticed this information on official web site of Soloud - http://sol.gfxile.net/soloud/c_api.html
so i guess we need only one file: soloud_c.cpp
let's try to just include it in SoloudStatic.vcxproj file generated by you with Genie. like this:

```
..
<ClCompile Include="..\..\src\c_api\soloud_c.cpp">
</ClCompile>
..
```

and recompile our static library. i use this command in powershell:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe' /p:PlatformToolset=v142`;WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=10`;Configuration=Release`;Platform=x64 .\SoloudStatic.vcxproj
```

but you can compile how you want. just make sure that it's architecture is really x64. you can check it with this command:

```
dumpbin /headers soloud_static_x64.lib | more
```

finally just link it with your nim file. add this line to the top:

```
{.link:"soloud_static_x64.lib".}
```

and compile nim file with this command:

```
nim c --cc:vcc --dynlibOverride:libsoloud.dll -r "examples\00-ogg\Example00_ogg.nim"
```